# Short cartoon movie - Princess(?) turns evil

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I have been searching for the title of a short 80s or 90s cartoon movie about a  teenage girl (a princess?) who turns bad. You can tell that she's bad because her clothes and makeup goes black. At the end she turns back to being good.

There was something about rainbows and maybe a horse?

It might be Canadian.

Comment: I'm sure you can do better than this. Have a look through the checklists [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can add anything.

Comment: How old was the girl? When did you see this? How do you know she turned bad? How did she turn bad? Why did she turn good? What was the setting? Where did you see it? Who were the other characters involved?

Comment: I remember rainbows and maybe a horse. 80s or 90s

Comment: She was a teenager. She turn bad because her clothes and makeup was black

Answer (score 1):

Could this be "[Rainbow Brite and the Star-Stealer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Brite_and_the_Star_Stealer)"?

> When Rainbow Brite (Bettina Bush) and her magical horse, Starlite
>   (Andre Stojka), go to Earth to start spring, they meet Stormy (Marissa
>   Mendenhall), another magical girl who controls winter with her horse,
>   Skydancer (Peter Cullen). She, however, doesn't want to end her winter
>   fun, so Rainbow battles her for control over the season. She proves to
>   be no match for Rainbow and Starlite, who outrun her and head off to
>   Earth. When they arrive, they meet up with Brian (Scott Menville), the
>   only boy on Earth who can "see" them.

Comment: I thought it was but no this was a movie and girl was different

Comment: @Cassaundra: Er... what Valorum references above is also a movie, based off of the TV show. Or are you saying this isn't a cartoon? Or not attached to a property that you know of?

Comment: It is a cartoon. Maybe I'll check it out and see thank you

Comment: No it's not rainbow brite :(

Comment: Any luck? I'm still looking things up